# Save and read data from plist?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have some data stored in a plist and displayed in a tableview. It's an array of dictionaries. It looks something like this:

```
  <array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Title 1</string>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>test.png</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Description 1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Title 2</string>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>test2.png</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Description 2</string>
    </dict>
```

How can I extract the data to save the items from the first dictionary into a new plist so I can display it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is how You extract the array from plist:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: To get the items from the first dictionary you'll additionally have to say `NSDictionary* firstDict = [contentArray objectAtIndex:0];`.